# Failed Magento SUPEE 6482 Security Check (APPSEC-1030) with Version 1.9.3.7 CE

Tags: patches, security, magento1.9.3.7, supee-6482

The new [Magento Security Scanner](https://account.magento.com/scanner) reports that there are **vulnerabilities** on the website and that **patch** [SUPEE 6482](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6482) is required. This occurs even when there are no **Modules enabled**.

[image: Magento Security Scanner Result]

However, we are currently running 1.9.3.7 and the same fixes from **SUPEE 6482** were applied in 1.9.2.1. There is no download available for **SUPEE 6482** for any version of Magento after 1.9.2.0.

Also confusing is that the specific vulnerability, called `APPSEC-1030`, only affected the Enterprise Edition of Magento prior to 1.14.2.1.

The **SUPEE 6482** patch for 1.8.1.0 - 1.9.2.0 modifies the following files:

> app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php
>   app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php

I have verified that these changes are already present, so applying the old SUPEE 6482 patch would do nothing. Additionally, none of these changes appear to address the `APPSEC-1030` issue.

I am reasonably sure that this vulnerability - as it originally appeared in Magento - does not exist, but I am concerned that something else is re-introducing the same issue.

**How do I determine exactly why this security check is failing?**

Answer (score 1):

Join the club.

I have the same failed security scan and like yourself I checked the files and all is as it should be with the SOAP adapter updates.

My test failed on Enterprise, patched to the latest and greatest. I did actually have a fail on SUPEE-8788 too, however, once I removed the .swf uploader files all was fixed - that patch had worked but left some binaries around for the admin flash uploader.

I am satisfied for now that I have the patches patched, however, in SUPEE-6482 you may want to see if there is anything going on with extra files left around. The scan code is a black box, who knows what it does and whether this error is with us or them.

Comment: Github knows, the code for the security scanner is on Github somewhere. I don't have a link handy, but a black box it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP opcode caches (APC/XCache/eAccelerator) make sure to flush it (or restart webserver) after patching, otherwise code will continue to run from caches.

Sometimes you need to upload the patched files yourself, depending on your server configuration. Running the patch script with the wrong user can result in problem.

I would suggest looking at the link below:

https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-6482-without-ssh/